# Uncertainty principle from QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

**Is it possible to derive uncertainty principle from QFT?**

Which kinds of perturbation (particles, monopoles, ...) are rule out by this principle?

Comment: Note that position is not observable in QFT, so how would you define $\Delta x$?

Comment: @Phoenix87, yes I agree with you. QM as limit of QFT is quite peculiar, as I now understand

Answer (score 1):

The uncertainty principle is inherent in the properties of all wave-like systems, and it arises in QM (quantum mechanics) simply due to the matter wave nature of all quantum objects. The uncertainty principle is embedded in the commutator of position $x$ and momentum $p$ operators, which does not vanish.

As QFT (quantum field theory) is QM with many degrees of freedom, i.e. with an infinite number of harmonic oscillators, the uncertainty principle is implicitly comprised in QFT, via the commutator relations between the fields $\phi$ and the conjugate momenta $\pi$.

Comment: How to reproduce uncertainty principle $\Delta x \Delta p ≥ \hbar/2$ from QFT?

Comment: A realistic particle, i.e. a particle localized in a limited spacetime region, can be described as a Gaussian wave packet. The definite momenta states compounding the field $\phi (x)$ to be modulated by a Gaussian profile. In this way the approximations both in space and momentum are related by the uncertainty product.